# Search By Date in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, datetime

We just upgraded to SQL Server 2012 from 2005.  While I'm a novice, something this simple couldn't be this difficult.  I used to be able to pull data from a table based on the date vs date and time.  As it now stands I have:

```
Select * from receipts_table where receipt_cancel_date = '2013-09-20'
```

before we upgraded this would work fine.  How can I run this and actually get the desired results as I know there's receipts with a cancel date of 2013-09-20.

Thanx

Comment: Are you expecting all records that fall on the date of '2013-09-20'? Regardless of the Time portion?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing string for a date parameter, best format is ISO (`yyyymmdd`) format. Otherwise even though your string work in some servers it might not work in another depending on the culture of the server. `ISO format is culture independent`.

Also remove the time part from `receipt_cancel_date` column by converting it to a DATE (if DATETIME) for comparison purpose.

Try this:

```
Select * from receipts_table 
where convert(date, receipt_cancel_date) = convert(date,'20130920')
```

Or use *120 style* with your format:

```
Select * from receipts_table 
where convert(date, receipt_cancel_date) = convert(date,'2013-09-20',120)
```